# Why Android-Volley is faster

Tags: android, android-volley

I am evaluating the Volley networking library for using in my next project as I heard many good things about it. I found that it makes implementing network operations easy. But it's also claimed that it makes networking faster. Can someone please explain how?

Comment: Your question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: I think it's an excellent question. In the Volley documentation, it states the following. "Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster." http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't increase the speed of the networking itself, but it has good support for local caching and response compression, which are things that the standard Java/Apache HTTP classes don't handle for you.

The result is the perception of increased performance, and also lower battery usage (due to fewer network fetches).

Having adopted Volley for my own projects over the past few weeks, I can firmly recommend it!

Answer (score 3):

At this year's I/O there is a session about that, presented by the 
Ficus Kirkpatrick. I suggest you to watch that video, as it will answer your questions in detail.
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728